# setting and reading cookies in mod_python (apache)

Tags: python, apache, cookies, session-cookies, mod-python

I've seen plenty of things explaining how to read and write cookies, however, I have no clue about how to do it in mod_python in apache. I tried putting this at the start of my HTML code, but it says to put it in the HTTP header. How do I do that?
Also, how do I retrieve them? I was originally looking mainly at this site:
http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_set_the_cookie

My code currently starts like this (and it displays as part of the HTML)

```
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: test=1
<html>
    <head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_python is not CGI, and provides it's own way to set and read cookies:

```
from mod_python import Cookie, apache
import time

def handler(req):
    # read a cookie
    spam_cookie = get_cookie(req, 'spam')

    # set a cookie
    egg_cookie = Cookie.Cookie('eggs', 'spam')
    egg_cookie.expires = time.time() + 300
    Cookie.add_cookie(req, egg_cookie)

    req.write('<html><head></head><body>There's a cookie</body></html>')
    return apache.OK
```

You'll find more documentation here :  http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-cookie.html

Comment: Just a question while we're at it: is this a legacy app you have to maintain ? Else - if it's for a new project and you have any choice I'd strongly suggest you use mod_wsgi instead.